# How can I post or put to MVC Web API? Nothing has worked so far

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to post my form data to MVC Web API. I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried lots of examples found online, the lastest is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1).
Here's my model

```
public class UserModify
{
    public string AdminADID;
    public string EmpID;
    public string ADID;
    public string PG;
    public bool KE;
    public bool SME;
    public bool Enabled;
    public int RoleID;
}
```

And my Post method

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(string id, Models.api.UserModify PostData)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && PostData != null)
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
            {
                Content = new StringContent($"id: {id}, AdminADID: {PostData.AdminADID}")
            };
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

    }
```

From Fiddler, this is what's being sent

```
POST http://wksp0008c82b:55555/TPD2/TPD2/api/Users/6502 HTTP/1.1 
Host: wksp0008c82b:55555 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0 
Accept: */* 
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
Referer: http://wksp0008c82b:55555/TPD2/TPD2/Admin/Users 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest 
Content-Length: 100 
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=ezck3asbgfpokixxtt0mazwp 
DNT: 1 
Connection: keep-alive 
Authorization: Negotiate <shortened>AA==

AdminADID=XXX1YYY&EmpID=1234567&ADID=AAA2BBB&PG=ProgramGroup&KE=false&SME=true&Enabled=true&RoleID=5
```

This is what's coming back

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 21
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate oRswGaADCgEAoxIEEAEAAABR+MD7yC/OYgAAAAA=
Date: Wed, 31 Jul 2019 16:20:57 GMT

id: 6502, AdminADID:
```

So how do I get it to see my posted data?  I've also tried the [FromBody] attribute on the parameter but no joy there either.

EDIT: Found my mistake.  The model must be properties, not fields.

Comment: Since I'm not seeing any "errors" (e.g. HTTP 404), I'm not sure you're actually doing anything "wrong".  Maybe the problem is just the way you're using Fiddler. 
 SUGGESTIONS: 1) Set a breakpoint in your "POST" handler, 2) Try [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/)

Comment: Set a breakpoint as paulsm4 said, check that you are getting value in postdata variable. If not then maybe something wrong with the model binding

Comment: From body is not needed as model binding will automatically look in body for your model as it's not a simple type

Comment: Ok, so I used Postman, got the same result as fiddler.  Added a breakpoint and all fields in the model are null (strings are null, bools are false, int is 0)

Comment: Ok, found my issue.  I'm so dense.  The model must be made up of properties and not fields.  It works now.